# Trying to get property of non-object for get_user_by

Tags: php, wordpress, properties

I keep receiving the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /path/converter.php on line 169
```

My code:

```
$userWP = get_user_by('login' ,$roww['username']);   // line 168
$user_id_wp = $userWP->ID;                           // line 169
echo "UserID WP:".$user_id_wp."<br />";              // line 170
```

I just don't understand what it's looking for, or what I'm doing wrong... could someone please assist? Thank you so much

Not sure if it helps, but here is the section of code I'm working on, it's a migration script for `vbulletin CMS` to `Wordpress`: Lines 154 thru 178

```
   if ( $row['associatedthreadid'] != 0 ) {
      echo $queryx = "SELECT postid,pagetext,username,userid,parentid,dateline FROM post WHERE threadid ='".$row['associatedthreadid']."' ORDER BY parentid,postid ASC";
      echo "<br />";
      $resultsx = $conn->query($queryx);
      $LastCommentID = 0;
      $IDPrincipal = "";
      $ArrayComment = array();
          while ( $roww = $resultsx->fetch_array( MYSQLI_ASSOC ) )
          {
              echo "UserName CMS:".$roww['username']."<br />";
              if( $roww['userid']==1 ){
                  global $wpdb;
                  $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_users SET user_login='".$roww['username']."', user_nicename='".$roww['username']."',display_name='".$roww['username']."' WHERE ID='".$roww['userid']."'");
              }
              $userWP = get_user_by( 'login',$roww['username'] );
              $user_id_wp = $userWP->ID;
              echo "UserID WP:".$user_id_wp."<br />";
              if( $roww['parentid']==0 ) {
                  $IDPrincipal = $roww['postid'];
              } else {
                  if( $IDPrincipal==$roww['parentid'] ){
                      $parentID = 0;
                  } else {
                      $parentID = $ArrayComment[$roww['parentid']];
                  }
```

Comment: This means `get_user_by()` is not returning an object with an `ID` property, check the documentation for that function or see how you have defined it. I also wonder if `$roww` is spelled properly on line 168?

Comment: Thank you @wlh , I updated my OP for clarification.  ( $roww is spelled properly )

I'm not sure what to update to fix it, It's grabbing the usernames/ID's corresponding to the Associatedthreadid ...

Comment: According to Wordpress Codex, `get_user_by()` will return `false` if no user is found. Check for the value of `$userWP` before trying to get the `ID` property. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/

Comment: @wlh, Thank you for your help!  Is there a way to assign a user if one isn't found,rather than skipping the entry?

Comment: You'll have to figure out how this works with your code, but see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, all that is a bit above my ability, atm, I've spent years using html & css. I'm a bit lost trying to get the syntax right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bit suspicious:

```
if( $roww['userid']==1 ){
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_users SET user_login='".$roww['username']."', user_nicename='".$roww['username']."',display_name='".$roww['username']."' WHERE ID='".$roww['userid']."'");
}
```

You update only if userid==1?

> Is there a way to assign a user if one isn't found,rather than
>   skipping the entry?

```
$userWP=get_user_by( 'id', '1' );  //your fallback-user
if(get_user_by( 'login',$roww['username'] )!==false) {
    $userWP=get_user_by( 'login',$roww['username'] );
}
```

Comment: I apologize, I didn't really understand how this site worked, came back to give you some Appreciation on your answer.